# Absolute element breaks underlying hover effect

Tags: html, css, hover

Got an image filter on hover and there is an absolute div on top of it, which cancels the hover effect of underlying image when hover. I need the image filter stay even when .absolute is hover

simplified html

```
<div class="parent">
   <div class="absoulte"><p>Hover bttn</p></div>
   <img src="blabla.jpg">
</div>
```

and the css

```
.parent img:hover{
filter: brightness(0.5) saturate(0.4) hue-rotate(190deg);
}
.absoulte {
   width:100%; 
   position:absolute;
   text-align:center;
   opacity:0;
   z-index:9 
   bottom:100px;
}
.parent:hover .vieitembtn {opacity:1;}
```

Comment: Fixed it. Copied the main points of the styling, and sleep depravation takes its tall

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the problem is bad syntax.

You need a value for `text-align` (or remove it altogether) and closing semicolons on all properties.

**Fixed CSS:**

```
.parent img:hover{
    filter: brightness(0.5) saturate(0.4) hue-rotate(190deg);
}
.absoulte {
   width:100%; 
   text-align:center;
   center;opacity:0;
   z-index:9;
   bottom:100px;
}
.parent:hover .vieitembtn {opacity:1;}
```

Comment: My bad. Text-align does have value;

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to add -webkit-filter: instead of just filter I made a jsfiddle for you you dont really need all of that other stuff though I am not sure what you are trying to do though...
http://jsfiddle.net/322kxppm/

```
<div class="parent">
<p>Hover button</p>
<img src="http://www.clickerzoneuk.co.uk/cz/wp-content/uploads/2010/10/PuppySmall.jpg"/>
```

```
.parent{
text-align: center;
}

img:hover{
    -webkit-filter: brightness(.5) saturate(.4) hue-rotate(190deg);
}
```

Comment: there are prefixes for all the browsers. didn't want to flood the post with them.